# how to query mysql relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

1. `role`
2. `user`
3. `user_role`

`role` contains two rows which are `role_id` and `role`,

and `user` contains, `user_id`, `fname`, `lname`, `mname`, `birthday`.

and `user_role` contains `ur_id`, `role_id`, `user_id`.

I'm trying to figure out how to query out all `user` with the `role` of `teacher`?

something like this:

```
Fname   | Lname  | Role     | birthdate
robert  | foo    | teacher  | 10-12-15
```

Comment: We can't answer that question if we dont know the names of the columns

Comment: You need always to add some preview of you tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use joins to acquire your output. This might be helpful to gain it.

```
Select u.fname as Fname, u.lname as Lname, r.role as Role, DATE_FORMAT(u.birtday,'%d-%m-%Y') as birthdate from user u 
join user_role ur on u.user_id = ur.user_id 
join role r on ur.role_id = r.role_id 
where r.role = "teacher";
```

and for better output please update your question with expected answer

Answer (score 1):

Refer below link for inner join tutorial

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

```
SELECT * FROM role 
INNER JOIN  user_role  ON role.role_id = user_role.role_id 
INNER JOIN  user ON user_role.user_id= user.user_id 
WHERE role.role="teacher";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, u.mname, u.birth,r.role FROM user_role ur WHERE 
                ur.user_id=(SELECT u.user_id FROM user u) AND 
                ur.role_id=(SELECT r.role_id FROM role r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. 
`SELECT u.fname, u.lname, r.role, u.birthdate FROM user AS u, role AS r, user_role AS ur WHERE u.user_id = ur.user_id AND r.role_id = ur.role_id`